# Error on Key Bindings opening Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have the same settings for Sublime Text 2 on my two machines; anyway, on one I get this error every time I open it:

```
Error trying to parse file: Expected value in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap:2:1
```

I don't have anything in my User Key Bindings though.
Any ideas?

Comment: What does that file contain? Here, on Windows, it is just a pair of square brackets each on their own line.

Comment: @Richard it looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f917hmkt4mumd33/Screenshot%202015-03-30%2010.59.08.png?dl=0)

Comment: Better to show the file content not an image (but based on the error, I would start by removing the comment: line 2 column 1 …)

Comment: Thank you @Richard sorry for being clumsy... when I looked at 2:1 I thought "how could a comment create such a problem?" I'll remove it and see :)

Comment: @Richard nothing. Still showing the same error with the same reference. I am thinking of re-install Sublime, so then I can compare and maybe understand what was messed up.